# Discriminant remains unchanged when reducing mod p

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $ \theta $ be an algebraic integer and let $g(t) \in \mathbb Z [ t ] $ be its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb Q$. Let $ \bar g (t) \in \mathbb F_p [ t] $ be the same polynomial with coefficients reduced mod $p$. How to prove the discriminant is unchanged, i.e. $ \overline {\text{disc} ( g (t) ) } = \text{disc} ( \bar g (t) ) $?

---

Of course $ \text{disc } (g (t)) \in \mathbb Z$. And is equal to $ \Pi_{ i < j } ( x_j - x_i ) $ where $x_1,...,x_n $ are roots of $g(t)$ in some splitting field. But I can't go any further, any help is appreciated.

Comment: discriminant of $g$ can be expressed as a polynomial (with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$ !) in the coefficients of $g$

Comment: @user8268 Thanks! I looked it up, it can actually be expressed as a polynomial in the coefficients of $g$, using the resultant of $g$ and $g'$, which is the determinant of the Sylvester matrix. And it's kind of complicated for me to understand why the resultant is the determinant of the Sylvester matrix. Is there a easier way to see it?

Comment: @user112564: you don't need a Sylvester matrix. Do you understand how to use the symmetric function theorem and the fact that $g(t)$ is monic with algebraic integer roots to show the discriminant of $g(t)$ must be an integral polynomial in the coefficients of $g(t)$?

Comment: @KCd Ok, I know how to do that now. But I've come up with a new quesiton: how do I know the polynomial in the coefficients of $g(t)$ when calculating disc$(g)$ is the same as (mod $p$ of course) the polynomial in the coefficients of $\bar g(t) $ when calculating disc$(\bar g) $?

Comment: @user8268 The same question.

Comment: @user112564: try to understand the quadratic and cubic cases: if $g(t) = t^2 + bt + c$, why should ${\rm disc}(\overline{g}) = b^2 - 4c \bmod p$, and if $g(t) = t^3 + bt + c$, why should ${\rm disc}(\overline{g}) = -4b^3 - 27c^2 \bmod p$?